# I need a code which sums different numbers

Tags: python-2.7

I got a very difficult assignment as I am new to python, I hope you will be able to help me.
I wrote this code:

```
def hours_per_student(student_course,course_hours):
    new={}
    for key in student_course.keys():
        for val in student_course.values():
               for m in range(len(val)):
                   if not new.has_key(key):
                        new[key]=course_hours[val[m]]
                   else: 
                        new[key]=new[key]+course_hours[val[m]]

    return new
```

for these dictionaries:

```
student_course = {'rina' : ['math', 'python'], 'yossi' : ['chemistry', 'biology'], 'riki' : ['python']}
course_hours = {'math' : 4, 'python' : 4, 'chemistry' : 6, 'biology' : 5}
```

And I need to get this:

```
hours_per_student(student_course, course_hours)
```

to return this:

```
{'rina': 8, 'yossi': 11, 'riki': 4}
```

But I keep getting identical numbers for each key.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be iterating over `.values()` if you're already iterating over `.keys()`, just use the key to get the value. Or where you have `for m in len(val)`, just do `for m in val` and then reference `m` instead of `val[m]`(the naming here stinks but I discuss that later). Python is much better at iteration than that. For instance, instead of the line

```
for val in student_course.values():
```

you should try something like

```
for courses in student_course[key]:
    for course in courses:
        if key not in new:
            new[key] = course_hours[course]
        else:
            new[key] += course_hours[course]
```

Naming your variables intelligently will make it easier for you to keep track of what's happening. For example, each value in `student_course` is a list of courses, so you should name it that, not something ambiguous like `val`. Similarly, each element in `courses` is the name of a course, so name it as such.

Comment: Thankyou! I have tried you'r solution bul i got this error annoncment: new[key]=course_hours[course]
KeyError: 'm'                                                                                                
 Do you know how can I fix it? Or what does it mean?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your complete updated code

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
solution = {student: sum([hours.get(course, 0) for course in s_courses]) for student, s_courses in student_course.items()}
```

Comment: this isn't helpful at all - they're clearly is having trouble understanding basic control flow tools - introducing high-level comprehensions is just going to exacerbate those issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things I found lacking in your code:

1. When iterating over your students, you could have just created a key for each of them, and then add the hours per course.
2. Naming variables so you understand what they mean is confused, refrain from using `new`, `key` or `val`.
3. You don't have to use `keys()` function, iterating a dictionary using `for key in dictionary` works the same way.

Here's a fixed code snippet:

```
def hours_per_student(students, course_hours):
    total_hours = {}
    for student in students:
        courses = students[student]
        total_hours[student] = 0
        for course in courses:
            total_hours[student] += course_hours[course]
    return total_hours
```